# How to use 300 dpi images of .eps file in Latex

Tags: includegraphics

can anyone tell how to fix a good resolution of .eps file in Latex, as I have used these images and it has been stretched, cover most of the length in the text. I am unable to increase the width of images while image resolution is good. Only problem is, it has been elongated horizontally.
Help me please.

Comment: Do you just want `\includegraphics[width=whatever]{image}`? If not, please edit your question to show an example code that reproduces the problem. Also, note that 'true' eps files are resolution independent, so using 300dpi doesn't really make sense (though of course eps files can contain bitmaps).

Comment: your question is not at all clear (most eps files are vector format so don't have a resolution, and most people use pdflatex rather than latex, which can not directly include eps, they have to be converted to pdf first)  also if you mean the images are distorted, are you specifying both height= and width= to `\includegraphics` ? If so only specify height or width, not both.